# Multiple columns from join tables are not returned by activerecord in rails3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this query which when run in mysql cli gives the proper result but not when executed by rails

Query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.event_id, t2.content, t2.created_at, t3.title FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.event_id 
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.id 
WHERE (t1.id in (SELECT id FROM t4 WHERE attr = 20)) 
ORDER BY t1.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

I used

```
t1.find_by_sql "<above_sql_query>"
```

but it only returns those columns that concern t1. The result is an array:

```
[#<t1 id: 3, event_id: 3>]
```

I also tried with

```
t1.find(:all, :select => "<select attributes as above>", :joins => "as above", :conditions => "as above", :limit => 15, :order => "t1.created_at DESC")
```

but still gives the same result, only returns attributes concerning t1. Please help me in finding the best way to execute that command.

Thanks, pR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `.includes` solved this problem for me.